# script for telerik mvc grid gets registered on page but is not firing

Tags: telerik-mvc

I have implemented telerik's mvc grid in my .net application. I am using features such as filtering, grouping etc. The problem is that the javascript/jquery required to execute these features is not working. I can see the script registered when i do view source for the page but the script doesnt fire. Where should i look to check if anything is missing? Could it be possible that the existing script files are preventing the script file for telerik from running? If yes, how can i verify this? Following is a snippet from the view source file which shows that script has been registered for the page.

//

Answer (score 1, accepted):

script register should be at the end of your site master page. it is better to use firebug to see whats gong on try to reach the cause through debugging. there may be some javascript error on your page

Comment: I have used @Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar(); in layout.cshtml to register the script files. This statement is at the end of the layout.cs. The layout.cshtml is lying in a different project. I am using it in my project to render the views. 

Comment: have u tried to use firebug is there any javascript error and in the net tab of firebug see if the scripts are loading. One more thing is to comment the .compress(true) and .combined(true)

Comment: I used firebug. It shows that the required jquery files have been loaded in the page. I put a breakpoint on the functions/statements which that should be hit. However, the breakpoints don't get hit. The functions are there but they are not getting called or executed. I can't figure out why.

Comment: How do i show a screenshot? I cant upload an image. According to Stackoverflow i dont have the required reputation

Comment: which version of query you r using. what actually happen when you click on sortable column header. Try to add some code otherwise it is very difficult to guess what is wrong

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/script-for-telerik-mvc-grid-gets-registered-on-page-but-is-not-firing.aspx. This post may give you some idea

Comment: Call jquery files before the script register

Comment: On pageload when i run firebug, it hits telerik.panelbar.js for the first time and gives the error given below. after page load is complete, the .js file never gets called     jQuery("#PanelBar").tPanelBar is not a function
(?)()Index....ndex=25 (line 29583)
d(d=Document Index.aspx?index=25, f=[function()])jquery....min.js (line 16)
d(a=undefined)jquery....min.js (line 16)
d()

Comment: put jquery(false) in script register and call jquery files mannually BEFORE the script register